# Firestore client throws dependency mismatch even when it's imported

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, protobuf-java

I am using firestore in my application and On the call of method

```
 Firestore firstoreDB = FirestoreClient.getFirestore(FirebaseApp.getInstance(env));
```

getting exception :

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.v1beta1.stub.GrpcFirestoreStub.<clinit>(GrpcFirestoreStub.java:73)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.spi.v1beta1.GrpcFirestoreRpc.<init>(GrpcFirestoreRpc.java:133)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:80)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:72)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:512)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions.getFirestoreRpc(FirestoreOptions.java:315)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.<init>(FirestoreImpl.java:76)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:63)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:56)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:499)
    at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.<init>(FirestoreClient.java:47)
    at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.<init>(FirestoreClient.java:27)
    at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient$FirestoreClientService.<init>(FirestoreClient.java:87)
    at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.getInstance(FirestoreClient.java:77)
    at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.getFirestore(FirestoreClient.java:70)
    at com.mmt.app.firebase.ConnectToAgent.sendMessage(ConnectToAgent.java:94)
    at com.mmt.app.firebase.TestFB.connectToAgent(TestFB.java:37)
    at com.mmt.app.firebase.TestFB.main(TestFB.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
```

I know is dependency mismatch and gave tried every permutation of firebase admin and firestore + guava version but no luck .

My current POM is :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>24.1.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-firestore</artifactId>
    <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Try to add: <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I checked your dependencies with `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` and found `com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3` is included in protobuf-java-3.9.1.jar. Strange. Would you create a dummy GitHub project to reproduce the error?